# запрос Count по датам и по значению

Tags: sql-server, select

у меня есть таблица TICKET в нем столбцы 
id (id), 
DEALDATE (datetime), 
Transactio (Varchar), 
session (Varchar).

В Transactio находиться операции например продажа, возврат итд. 
в session значение например ЮТ, S7. U6 итд.

Мне необходимо сделать запрос по количеству дня по операциям "Продажа" группировать по значению (session) помогите пожалуйста

[image]

Comment: Группируйте по сессии **И** дате.

Answer (score 0):

Раз в условии нужна группировка по сессиям, а отдельного столбца под тип транзакции нет, то предполагая, что тип транзакции есть столбец "Transaction" и требуется узнать кол-во дней продаж в разрезе каждой сессии, тогда запрос будет иметь вид:

```
select count(*) as CntDays from TICKET WHERE Transactio = 'продажа' GROUP BY session
```